# Python Matplotlib Plotting Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm attempting to plot a stacked bar chart from a data frame with two series.  The second series has a very small amount of data but I expect it to still be visible in the chart as a small maroon line.  When I save the chart as a png file the first two bars do not show the second "Drivers" dataset.  However subsequent bars all show them. Below is the code I am using along with the snapshot of the chart. You can see that the "Drivers" series is not showing in the first two bars? How can I remedy this?

Code:

```
df_trend = pd.read_csv('test_log.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=0)
df_trend.index = (pd.to_datetime(df_trend.index)).strftime("%m/%d %H:00")

fig = plt.figure()
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = df_trend.shape[0], 4
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
y = df_trend.tail(24).plot.bar(stacked=True, color=['skyblue', 'maroon'], edgecolor="none", width=0.2)
y.legend(loc="lower left", fontsize=9)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=9)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.title('Cars vs Drivers', fontsize=10, y=1.05)
plt.savefig('cars_drivers.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

DataFrame Used:

```
               Cars  Drivers
09/27 09:00  243000      300
09/28 09:00  243970      190
09/28 13:00  267900      290
09/28 17:00  254770      180
09/28 18:00  250860      290
```

Chart:
[image: plot chart output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I think you can do, but I think you want # 2:

1. Don't use a stacked bar plot (this is my first choice).
2. Increase DPI of figure: `plt.savefig('cars_drivers.png',
   bbox_inches='tight',dpi=1000)`.
3. Change `ylim` range: `plt.ylim([200e3, 300e3])`.
4. Change scale of drivers and rename column to show in legend:

   `df_trend['Drivers'] = 10*df_trend['Drivers']`

   `df_trend = df_trend.rename(columns={'Drivers': 'Drivers x 10'})`

Comment: First thank you for providing multiple solutions. I also agree solution 1 is best but a stacked bar graph is desired by the recipient. I tried all of the options but Option 3 was the only one that worked for me. Thank you Gerges.